# Waiting for the GUI to fully update?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have some tabs with scrollable panels that contain a series of labels. The labels may be "focused", in which case they are to remain perfectly centered, as tabs are switched, the window is resized, or font size is changed. I have all the math for that done. The only issue is *when* the code runs. The following function...

```
public void fixMargins() {
    //Top margin:
    final int top = (this.getHeight() - this.getVerseBlock(1).getHeight()) / 2;
    //Bottom margin:
    final int bottom = (this.getHeight() -this.getVerseBlock(this.view.getComponentCount()).getHeight()) / 2;
    this.view.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(top, 0, bottom, 0));
    //Set scroll bar accordingly:
    this.jumpCenter(this.focused);      
}
```

... will work sometimes. Seemingly every time when the window resizes, because dragging it causes an update every pixel. On maximizing, or on switching tabs after a redraw, it is not properly focused because it's using outdated numbers. I've confirmed this with console output.

I know exactly what needs to happen, but I only know an easy way in Node.js, which this certainly is not. Basically:

- External value updates - resize, font change, etc;
- Wait for layout to be **100% complete**, all labels and parents settled into new size;
- Apply margins according to new size;
- Wait for layout to update 100% again, scrollable range finalized;
- Move scroll bar to determined position using current numbers.

The following **do not** wait for the UI to fully update, for reasons I am unsure of:

```
revalidate()
doLayout()
SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
```

I'm about to just throw in a hack job that pauses a thread for one millisecond before running the code, but I figured I'd ask and see if there is any sort of convenient waitForLayoutUpdate() function that I just haven't found yet.

Upon further research, I have discovered that the JLabels specifically are not reporting a correct height at the time that it is checked. This is a known issue with them, but I have yet to find a work-around.

Comment: 1. SwingWorker.invokeLater()  doesn't exists, 2. doLayout() is for JComponents thats implements Scrollable (is too hacky to override correctly for JPanel with Scrollable) inside JScrollPane, instead of global JFrame.pack(), 3. Runnable#Thread (with invokeLater) or SwingWorker#publish are for continious/batch updates, 4. revalidate/repaint called to the close container can do that, but not designed for application compiled in Java7 (removed all thread safety implemented in Swing APIs), nor in Java8 (minor changes in nested/inherits methods from Java essential classes)

Comment: *"..they are to remain perfectly centered.."* Put them as the only component of a `GridBagLayout` with no constraints.  Job done.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, that will definitely work out fine. The *series* of labels I specifically mentioned in a *scrollable* panel are definitely not a part of the design requirement, I was just doing that for funsies.